# Using transform to create clean looking cube

Tags: css, css-transforms

So there are lots of posts related to this but I can't seem to nail down exactly where I'm going wrong in my styles, so apologies if some of you see this as a rehash of previous questions.

This problem is very simple: I'm simply trying to build a random dice roll. The js works as expected, everything functions properly. The issue is that the cube just looks quite awkward, and I'm not entirely sure why. I'm usually pretty solid with css, but I don't do a lot of work with 3d transforms so there's a lack of intuition on my part. If you run the snippet you can see that not all the sides are smooth when the cube rotates, some sides look to be caved in and I'm not sure why (particularly the 1 and 2 sides). The full code is in the below snippet:

```js
const rollBtn = document.getElementById('roll');
const sides = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
const output = document.getElementById('dice_output');
let currentClass = '';

const rollDice = () => {
  let randomSide = sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6) + 1)];
  let currentSide = document.getElementById(randomSide);
  let generatedSide = `show-${randomSide}`;
  if (currentClass) {
    output.classList.remove(currentClass);
  }
  output.classList.add(generatedSide);
  currentClass = generatedSide;
}

rollBtn.addEventListener('click', rollDice);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.stage {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.btn-container {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.the-big-z {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.the-die {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.die-side {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20%;
  border: solid 3px teal;
}

#one { 
  transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(0px); 
}
#two { 
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(0px); 
}
#three { 
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(40px); 
}
#four { 
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px); 
}
#five { 
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(40px); 
}
#six { 
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px); 
}

#dice_output.show-one { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY(   0deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-two { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY( -90deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-three { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY(-180deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-four { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY(  90deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-five { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateX( -90deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-six { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateX(  90deg); 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="stage">
        <div id="dice_output" class="the-die">
          <div id="one" class="die-side">1</div>
          <div id="two" class="die-side" >2</div>
          <div id="three" class="die-side" >3</div>
          <div id="four" class="die-side" >4</div>
          <div id="five" class="die-side" >5</div>
          <div id="six" class="die-side" >6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button id="roll">roll the dice</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: notice that the transform applied to 1 is equivalent to none

Comment: Yep, as pointed out in the below response, literally just a typo that my eyes went blind to for some reason. It's always those small stupid things that bite you it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to translate the `#one` and `#two` to `40px`

```js
const rollBtn = document.getElementById('roll');
const sides = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
const output = document.getElementById('dice_output');
let currentClass = '';

const rollDice = () => {
  let randomSide = sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6) + 1)];
  let currentSide = document.getElementById(randomSide);
  let generatedSide = `show-${randomSide}`;
  if (currentClass) {
    output.classList.remove(currentClass);
  }
  output.classList.add(generatedSide);
  currentClass = generatedSide;
  
}

rollBtn.addEventListener('click', rollDice);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.stage {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.btn-container {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.the-big-z {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.the-die {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.die-side {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20%;
  border: solid 3px teal;
}

#one { 
  transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(40px); // Here
}
#two { 
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(40px); // And here
}
#three { 
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(40px); 
}
#four { 
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px); 
}
#five { 
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(40px); 
}
#six { 
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px); 
}

#dice_output.show-one { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY(   0deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-two { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY( -90deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-three { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY(-180deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-four { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateY(  90deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-five { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateX( -90deg); 
}

#dice_output.show-six { 
  transform: translateZ(-40px) 
  rotateX(  90deg); 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="stage">
        <div id="dice_output" class="the-die">
          <div id="one" class="die-side">1</div>
          <div id="two" class="die-side" >2</div>
          <div id="three" class="die-side" >3</div>
          <div id="four" class="die-side" >4</div>
          <div id="five" class="die-side" >5</div>
          <div id="six" class="die-side" >6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button id="roll">roll the dice</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy shit, code blindness is a real thing, literally just a typo that my eyes skated right past. This is a true facepalm moment, but sometimes a fresh pair of eyes catches dumb mistakes like that. Thanks man.

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone. You can accept if the answer helped you. :)